# Does having an M.Phil degree affect my chances of geting accepted for a PhD in the future?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, united-kingdom

I have completed my master's degree from a Russell Group university and I am planning to pursue a PhD degree in the future. Now, I have received an offer from a well known university in the UK. But due to lack of funding they are offering me an M.Phil degree of 2 years. My question is, if I pursue this degree and perhaps complete it successfully, will I be at a disadvantageous position when I apply for PhDs in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you will not be at a disadvantage. A two year MPhil degree should have at least some research and dissertation component. Doing well in the course and particularly in the research aspect should strengthen your PhD applications. You would also be able to ask your MPhil supervisor for a reference letter for those applications.

A word of caution: sometimes an offer of an MPhil due to lack of PhD funding is something of an implicit rejection, especially if the MPhil itself is unfunded. I would advise against undertaking an unfunded Masters or PhD. It's not worth it if you're not getting paid.